# PHP Zend 2: Fatal Error - Class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create own Model to do something (there will be calculations, moving in databases, and other non specifed work). But i got a problem, because I'm still getting and error that Class is not found.

Here is controller (module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php):

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Application\Model\Przesylki;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{    

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->layout('layout/layout');
    }

    public function cennikAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/pusty');
        $logika_paczki = new Przesylki();
        echo $logika_paczki->return_word();
    }
}
```

Module.php (module/Application/src/Module.php):

```
namespace Application;

use Main\Model\Przesylki;

class Module
{
    const VERSION = '3.0.2dev';

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

and a model, Przesylki.php (module/Application/src/Application/Model/Przesylki.php):

```
namespace Main\Model;

class Przesylki
{
    public function return_word() {
        return "word";
    }
}
```

if necessary, autoload_classmap.php (module/Application/src/autoload_classmap.php is just a

```
return array();
```

module.config.php:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            // Home
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'counter',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'work' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/work',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'cennik' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/cennik',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'cennik',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            // Panel
            'panel' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/panel',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\PanelController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'test' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/panel/test',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\PanelController::class,
                        'action'     => 'test',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Controller\PanelController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/panel'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/panel_layout.phtml',
            'layout/counter'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/counter.phtml',
            'layout/pusty'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/pusty.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Directories:

```
/config
    /autoload
/data
    /cache
/module
    /Application
        /config
            module.config.php
        /src
            /Application
                /Controller
                    IndexController.php
                    PanelController.php
                /Model
                    Przesylki.php
            autoload_classmap.php
            Module.php
        /test
        /view
/public
```

And when I run /cennik i got a Fatal, that class is not found:

```
[Tue Sep 06 08:58:20.446371 2016] [:error] [pid 4934] [client 195.8.99.234:1129] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Main\\Model\\Przesylki' not found in /var/www/Paczucha_pl/module/Application/src/Main/IndexController.php on line 27
```

Actual files and namespaces:

```
Przesylki.php - Application\Model
IndexController - Application\Controller
PanelController - Application\Controller
module.config.php - Application
Module.php - Application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally I found a solution. Correct structure for given namespaces is :

```
/module
     /Application
         /config
             module.config.php
         /src
             /Controller
                 IndexController.php   // => Namespace : Application\Controller
                 PanelController.php   // => Namespace : Application\Controller
             /Model
                 Przesylki.php         // => Namespace : Application\Model
         /view
         /index
             /index
         /panel
             /panel
```

There shouldnt be double Application folder. I think it's Zend 3, maybe it changed.

Answer (score 3):

You have problems with your namespaces. Your module's name is `Application` so your Model namespace should be `Application\Main\Model`.

Your module structure is not the recommended one for ZF2. It should be something as:

```
/module
     /Application
         /config
             module.config.ph
         /src
             /Application
                 /Controller
                     IndexController.php   // => Namespace : Application\Controller
                     PanelController.php   // => Namespace : Application\Controller
                 /Model
                     Przesylki.php         // => Namespace : Application\Model
         /view
             /index
                 /index
             /panel
                 /panel
```

Comment: Thanks for information. I tried to make directories as recommended, but right now all clasess can't be found, even index. I have changed code up there, can you check why why routing doesn't work?

Error code now:
[Tue Sep 06 11:23:59.214235 2016] [:error] [pid 4937] [client 195.8.99.234:59632] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\\Controller\\IndexController' not found in /var/www/Paczucha_pl/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Factory/$

Comment: @KarolGasienica Do you update all your namespaces after updating your module structure? You have to check the namespaces of your whole application, according to your module structure.

Comment: Are you able to check what's wrong? I think I set it all right...
https://github.com/Xantias/paczucha_public

Comment: @KarolGasienica I added the namespaces in my example. Please check you don't have typos in your directories names. Please have a look on ZF2 documentation, check your autoloader is OK, etc. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html I can't check your whole application...

Comment: There is nothing in yet :) It's almost clean app (only view is changed, but this doesnt matter). I will look later if i didnt make any mistake.

Comment: I have added all files with their namespaces up there, i havent any typos ... I have no idea why it doesnt run..